# Place text in standard position out of the bar in plotly chart

Tags: r, plotly

I have the column chart below and I want to place outside of the bars in specific position the value of the bar like percentage. For example (2%). But instead of text I get `Nan`

```
library(plotly)
Country<-c("EU","CHE","ITA")
Value<-c(3,2,1)

dat<-data.frame(Country,Value)


fig1 <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~Value, y = ~Country,
                type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',
                hovertemplate = paste('%{y}', '<br>Uptake first dose (%): %{x}<br><extra></extra>'),
                texttemplate = '%{y:.2s}', textposition = 'outside',
                marker = list(color = '#63bb47')
) 
fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(
  font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),
  yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",
               showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85)),
  xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE)) 

  
fig1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the mode to "text" and called the text argument with the Value variable.

```
library(plotly)
Country<-c("EU","CHE","ITA")
Value<-c(3,2,1)

dat<-data.frame(Country,Value)


fig1 <- plot_ly(dat, 
x = ~Value, 
y = ~Country,
type = 'bar', 
orientation = 'h',
hovertemplate = paste('%{y}', '<br>Uptake first dose (%): %{x}<br><extra></extra>'), 
mode = 'text',
text = paste(Value, '%'), 
textposition = 'outside',
arker = list(color = '#63bb47')
) 
fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(
  font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),
  yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",
               showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85)),
  xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE)) 


fig1
```

I think this is closer to the visualization your are seeking.
[image]

Comment: its almost full but I want the percentages text to remain black

Comment: this is why I took back the verification

Comment: accpted and created a new Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359971/color-specific-added-text-in-plotly-bar-chart